# convex set and polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra

A polyhedral convex set is defined by

$X=\{x\in R^n:<x,b_i> \leq B_i\} $

My question is :

Is a polyhedral convex set always compact? and what is the difference between a polytope and the set X?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that $X$ may be unbounded (and therefore not compact). For example, if you have only one $b_i$ and $B_i$, then the set $X$ is unbounded (for example, if $B_i\geq 0$, then if some $x$ satisfies the condition $\langle x, b_1\rangle =0$, then $\lambda x$ also satisfies the same condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand what is $\lambda$. Can I have an example of unbounded polyhedral convex set in $R^n$ with $n\geq  2$

Comment: @user486789 $\lambda$ can be any real number. An example of a polyhedral convex set in $\mathbb R^2$ would be $\{(x,y)| x+y \leq 0\}$ which is  clearly unbounded - for any $\lambda > 0$, the pair $(-\lambda, -0)$  is in the set, and the norm of that pair is $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you, now I see clearly